# Proving martingale properties

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis

I'm new to stochastic processes and have problems understanding martingales, conditional probability, $\sigma$-algebras etc.

I have two proofs that I'm now sure how to handle.

**Problem 1**.
Prove that an integrable stochastic process $\{X(t),\mathcal{F}_t, t\in \mathbb{T}\}$ is a martingale if and only if for any bounded predictable process $\{\xi(t),\mathcal{F}_t, t\in \mathbb{T}\setminus\{0\}\}$ we have that $E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\xi(k)\Delta X(k)\right]=0$.

**Attempt on Problem 1**

"$\Rightarrow$"

[image]

"$\Leftarrow$"

[image]

Am I correct? I'm not quite sure about the last step.

**Problem 2**.
Prove the equivalence of the following statements:

1. $\{X(t),\mathcal{F}_t, t\in \mathbb{T}\}$ is a martingale;
2. $X(t)=E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]$, $t\in \mathbb{T}$;
3. $E\left[\Delta X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=0$, $t=0,1,\ldots,T-1$.

Here $\Delta X(k)=X(k)-X(k-1)$.

**Attempt on Problem 2**

1. $\Rightarrow$ 2. Since $\{X(t),\mathcal{F}_t, t\in \mathbb{T}\}$ is a martingale, then $E[X(t)|\mathcal{F}_s]=X(s)$. Just take $t=T$ and $s=t\in T$ to get $$E[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t]=X(t)$$
2. $\Rightarrow$ 3.
   $$E\left[\Delta X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=E\left[X(t+1)-X(t)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=E\left[X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]-E\left[X(t)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=E\left[E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_{t+1}\right]|\mathcal{F}_t\right]-E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]-E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=0$$
   Am I correct here? The proof looks clumsy.
3. $\Rightarrow$ 1.
   $$E\left[\Delta X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=0$$
   $$E\left[X(t+1)-X(t)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=0$$
   $$E\left[X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=X(t)$$
   Am I correct here? Is it sufficient?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $2.\Longrightarrow 3.$ Can be simplified (and fixed):
$$
E\left[\Delta X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=E\left[X(t+1)-X(t)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]=E\left[X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]-\color{red}{E\left[X(t)|\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]}=0\,.
$$ Otherwise, Problem 2 looks good.

Comment: How did you get that the last difference equals 0? You somehow used 2.? What about problem 1?

Comment: $$E\left[X(t+1)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]-E\left[X(t)|\mathcal{F}_{t}\right]=X(t)-X(t)=0\,.$$ Let's get to Problem 1 once that is understood.

Comment: I understood this. You've used the martingale property 1. As for me, you've proved 1.->3., not 2.->3. Am I wrong?

Comment: I used 2. with $T=t+1\,.$ Edit: just realised that your 2. is messed up. It should be $$X(t)=E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\,,t\color{red}{\le}T\,.$$

Comment: It is clear to me now.

Comment: About Problem 1. It looks like in this discrete time setting predictable means that $\xi(k)$ is ${\cal F}_{k-1}$-measurable. To make your life simple and understand the idea at least: think of $\xi(k)$ as being an indicator function $1_A$ with $A\in{\cal F}_{k-1}\,.$ Then apply the definition of conditional expectation. To be honest: for a beginner I find that exercise slightly too advanced.

Comment: Back to Problem 2. Your edit $$X(t)=E\left[X(T)|\mathcal{F}_t\right]\,,t\in\mathbb T$$ is *incomplete*. This equation should hold only for $t\le T$ as I said. Exercise: what do you get from it  when $t>T\,?$

Comment: I will get $X(T)$, in my book $\mathbb{T}=\{0,1,\ldots,T\}$ Can you explain problem 1 in more detail?

Comment: Ah. Finally you are letting us know what $\mathbb T$ is. Acceptable but I would write it as in my comment further above using $t\le T\,.$

Comment: Honestly: I am too lazy to work out a full proof of problem 1. I gave a few hints already and want to see you working on them. To make your life further simple take just $\xi(k)\Delta X(k)$ and not a sum over $k\,.$ Proof ideas are more important than generality.

Comment: Can you give a hint how to add filtration/expected expectation to the proof? I've written the property of a martingale. I have unconditional expectation to work with. How to make it conditional?

Comment: That is my point. In problem 2 you have been working with conditional expectation all the time. If you don't know how that is defined attacking problem 1 even with my simplifications will be pointless. I do not want to give further hints that amount to a definition that you should look up somewhere else.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've added attempt in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direction $\Rightarrow$ in Problem 1 looks good. The other direction has a bit of a gap as you noticed. I would take for fixed $k$
$$
\xi(k):=1_{\textstyle\{\mathbb E[X(k)|{\cal F}_{k-1}]> X(k-1)\}}\,.
$$
and $\xi:\equiv 0$ for all other $k\,.$
Then
$$
\mathbb E\Big[\xi(k)\Big(X(k)-X(k-1)\Big)\Big]=0
$$
implies
$$
\mathbb E\Big[\xi(k)\Big(E[X(k)|{\cal F}_{k-1}]-X(k-1)\Big)\Big]=0
$$
and that implies $E[X(k)|{\cal F}_{k-1}]\le X(k-1)$ almost surely. The other inequality is shown similarly.